# Android onCreateOptionsMenu difference in Activity and Fragment with unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

Activity code snippet for onCreateOptionsMenu

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Fragment code snippet for onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

why are they different? Why can not I access R.menu.->unresolved reference. Invalidate cache/restart does not help. For example in fragment

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.????????????, menu)
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

Comment: Are you importing the same R file?

Comment: It was " import android.R "  i add   "com.example.myprojectname.R" and work. I don’t understand why the A studio itself doesn’t. Thanks It works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer above, it sounds like you had the incorrect R class imported.

It's a common problem to accidentally use `import android.R` instead of the R class associated with your project.